# Why Backspace key do not work in insert mode in shell file by default in Cygwin?

Tags: vimrc, microsoft-windows, cygwin

I am using cygwin to run "linux command line" on windows 10. But here, backspace key doesn't work in insert mode. I had to edit my .vimrc file by setting "nocompatible and "bs=2" to make it work (by watching a youtube tutorial). But why it doesn't work by default? Is this normal behavior of Vim?
Do backspace doesnt work on actual linux also??

Comment: Possibly, your Vim was in `compatible` mode. So you had to configure it for `nocompatible` mode

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt but i didn't set it in compatible mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backwards compatibility (with vi, and also with earlier Vim releases) is a big thing in Vim. However, there have been many complaints like yours in the past, so Vim 8.0 introduced a [`:help defaults.vim`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#defaults.vim) configuration that gets activated if there's no user configuration.

As you can see in [`:help 'backspace'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27backspace%27), the default is an empty option, and defaults.vim sets this to `indent,eol,start` (which you should use instead of the deprecated and difficult to understand value `2`).

> ```
> 'backspace' 'bs'        string  (default "", set to "indent,eol,start"
>                                                             in |defaults.vim|)
>                         global
> ```

`defaults.vim` has other sensible settings, and can be combined with customizations in your own `~/.vimrc`; it's worth to have a look!